# Multiple artificial neural networks

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I am trying to set up a Multiple Artificial Neural Network as you can see here on image (a):

[image]

([source](https://www.teco.edu/~albrecht/neuro/html/node32.html))

I want that each of the networks work independently on its own domain. The single networks must be built and trained for their specific task. The final decision will be make on the results of the individual networks, often called expert networks or agents.

Because of privacy, I could not share my data.

I try to set up this with Tensorflow in Python. Do you have an idea of ​​how I would do it if that is achievable? At the moment I have not found any examples of this.

Comment: Have you tried anything? There is no problem in doing that... assuming you have created and trained the "expert networks", just give them the same image to process and gather the results

Comment: Thank you for your help, The problem is that they are not simple images but neural networks that I want to integrate into input into the expert networks. To simplify, I would like to realize an learning of several learning

Comment: I'm sorry but you lost me, I don't know what are images that aren't simple images. Rethink your problem, try to figure out exactly what you don't understand and ask a very specific question...

Comment: could you share some made up data that is in the same structure as your data?

Comment: Question is not about the data (everything is int or float) but how to
structure the network to construct  as the figure (a) of following link in TensorFlow ?

Comment: I improved your question a little bit, but it looks as a "do my work instead me" question. You should get away this flavor from it on any cost, nobody likes it. You don't have to "share your data", particularly if there is nothing to share. But you *can* make your question more concrete, ask for some detail, *or* make clear that you are interested, for example, roughly into which direction should you start your project.

Comment: As a quick tip, I'm guessing you're looking at some extremely old machine learning sources. You should look at more modern resources, these styles of network models were abandoned a long time ago because they don't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to go about this is to just take the outputs of the two networks and concatenate the resulting output tensors (and reshape them if needed) and then pass them into the final network. Take a look at [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/concat) for the concatenation documentation and [here](https://github.com/lengstrom/fast-style-transfer/blob/master/src/optimize.py) for an example of taking the output from one network and feeding it into another. This should give you a place to start from.

As for (a), it is simple, just train the networks before hand and load them when you are training the final network. Then do the concatenation on the outputs.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your help! I think this is good for the realization of my project. Sorry for the question that was poorly formulated